# How to downgrade glibc 2.34 to glibc-2.27

Tags: glibc

I want to downgrade my "glibc 2.34" to version 2.27 because when I run `./test_121` on my machine it gave me this error:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by ./test_121)
```

My machine is using this version `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.5) 2.27`.

I installed the glibc 2.27 on my host and extracted it using `tar -xf glibc-2.27`, but I don't know how to execute it. or to do `gcc -o test_121` with the 2.27 compiler.

Comment: 1. How is this about programming? Sounds like general software problems. 2. How is this related to git? 3. Downgrading GLIBC is a terrible idea, it's a fundamental part of your distribution and unless you *know* that nothing depends on the current version that it *bound* to mess up your system. 4. You don't *execute* glibc, it's a library, it's really unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't have the privilege to upgrade to 2.34 on my machine so yea that's what im asking @JoachimSauer

Comment: So basically your distribution comes with a specific glibc version, that basically can't be changed, realistically. Ubuntu 18.04 came with 2.27, 20.04 came with 2.31, 22.04 cam with 2.35. It looks like your binary requires at least glibc 2.34 to run. So if you are currently using anything that doesn't have that version of glibc you won't be able to execute the binary. Did you build the binary? (I highly doubt it, as it would then not require a newer libc version) If not, where did you get it?

Comment: Nope i didn't build the binary. I just have access from my chief on the machine vps as a normal user, so yeah. But im just downloading the Ubuntu 18.04 so i can compile there

Comment: If you need to run that binary, you should get a more recent Ubuntu version (or another Linux distro with a sufficiently recent glibc). 22.04 (the current LTS release) should be able to run it. Why do you think 18.04 is the right version to run that on? It's a 4 year old release at this point. If your question is "how can I downgrade the glibc requirement for a given binary without re-compiling it from source" the answer to that is probably "you can't, unless you have an *insanely good* understanding of what goes on under the hood or get very, very lucky".

Answer (score 2):

> I want to downgrade my "glibc 2.34" to version 2.27 because when I run ./test_121 on my machine it gave me this error:

1. Downgrading GLIBC will very likely make your system unbootable.
2. You totally misunderstood the error -- your system *doesn't have* `GLIBC-2.34` in the first place -- it has `GLIBC-2.27`, downgrading from 2.27 to 2.27 makes no sense.

Your problem is that this binary: `./test_121` was built against `GLIBC-2.34` (or later) and *requires* that version (or newer) to run.

Your *only* choices are to run that binary on a newer system (or in a docker container with `GLIBC-2.34` or newer), *or* to get a different binary (one that requires `GLIBC-2.27` or older).

Comment: No what im doing is my laptop has 2.34 and my vps machine has 2.27 im trying to compile to my vps machine,  but my machine is 2.27 and im running 2.34. I understand what are you saying.It was just an idea if i could downgrade.

Comment: @RBCrax Compiling on VPS and running on the laptop _will_ work. It's the _opposite_ direction which doesn't.

Comment: @EmployedRussian could you elaborate on the last point please? I have cross-compiled binary with `GLIBC_2.34`, but the device has only `GLIBC_2.32` installed. How do I complile for `GLIBC_2.32` instead? I have installed _arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-9_ and _arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-10_, but none have `GLIBC_2.32`. I just do not understand what to Google for to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A binary requesting `GLIBC-2.34` means the binary was compiled against Glibc 2.34 or newer, and it depends on some ABI not available before that version, otherwise the dependency isn't created.

One option to workaround this is to tune the APIs used until you don't hit that requirement anymore (but it is problematic/difficult), you can find where the problem is by using `readelf -W -s` on the binary, this will show all the used symbols, those with an `@` in the name are versioned symbols.

The *proper* way to avoid this is to setup a "sysroot" tree resembling the intended target and cross-compile your application against it, using the `--sysroot` flag for the compiler (supported by GCC and Clang). The sysroot environment can be created by installing a system on an emulator or another machine then copying that, or using tools like `debootstrap` for Debian-based distros, `rinse` or `rhbootstrap` for redhat-based ones, etc, or you can create a generic one manually building the base system or using some build system (e.g. `buildroot` or `openembedded/poky`). In this way, the result will be guaranteed to work with the version it's compiled against.